# Java - jTable sort numbers

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, integer

I have searched for very long time so I have decided to write finally here. I have problem with sorting numbers (Integers, doubles, shorts) in a jTable, I have overwritten the getColumnClass method, however it still does not sort numbers correctly.

Here is what I did:

```
List<Class> types = new ArrayList();
    types.add(String.class);
    types.add(String.class);
    types.add(String.class);
    for (int s = 0; s < sloupce.size(); s++) {
    try {
        Statement st = log.getSt();
        ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '" + table + "' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" + sloupce.get(s) + "'");
        if (r.next()) {
            String typ = r.getString("DATA_TYPE");
            if (!typ.equals("varchar")) {
                types.add(Integer.class);
            } else { 
                types.add(String.class);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.toString()); }
    }

    DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][], new String[] {"         first column         ", "         second        ", "         another        "}) {


        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types.get(columnIndex);
        }

    };
```

Then I fill types array withproper classes, when I test the getColumnClass method it really returns proper class (java.lang.Integer), but it still sorts the values incorrectly.

//UPDATE:
I am representing a table from MySQL DB so I have updated my exact code how I am doing it.

Comment: You also need to add Integer objects to the table model, not String objects that happen to be numeric.

Comment: Please post [Minimal Code Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help

Comment: So can you show me how do I add "Integer objects" because my table should display any table from MySQL, so I never know if the next column will be integer or string.